# How to get permanent Facebook access token using java

Tags: facebook-access-token

If you using Facebook graph API, you can see all public information of someone if that person set those information public, only few things you need to do: open a browser, log-in to Facebook and know that person user ID#, for example, Mark Zuckerberg - facebook founder have user ID# 4, so go to:
https://graph.facebook.com/4 => you can see basic info such as name, age, location .... (imagine that you change i in _**https://graph.facebook.com/i** with i from 1 to 1 million, you may see info of million user as long as they set their info in public)

or go to this link you can see more information such as person favorites and education ...
_https://graph.facebook.com/4?access_token=**XXX** with **XXX** is a unique code, it changes every time you log-in to Facebook ( see more in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

My goal is using basic java url to go to these link and get all info (basically they are text) and save them to a text file, with _https://graph.facebook.com/4 there is no problem but with second link problem is the access token code which is XXX - changes every time or will be expired after 20~30 minutes so I can't run my program longer to get more data.
question is is there anyway to get a permanent access token or extend it for longer time, remember I only using a small java program, nothing to do with Facebook app or anything else. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't get a permanent access token but instead you can catch the error when the access token is expired and request a new one. Also you might want to read facebook terms of use to make sure you are not violating it.

Comment: ok so no way to get permanent code, got you, that was what I thinking. Do you have any idea or useful links, regards how to request a new access token every time you catching error? Those links I tried to search seem like rated to Facebook app developing which is not in my case. This data set I am trying to collect is for statistics purpose only, no personal info is being public or use for commercial purpose, example: I show you we have 30% people under 25 years old who live in America, study Information system is FEMALE...... and something like that.

Comment: Sorry I don't. I think you can only do so if you are working with a facebook app. (There might be an unadvertised workaround that I am not aware of though).

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the life of your access token to 60 days.
You can go through this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

If you make the following call from your server side, Facebook will return you an access token which will be valid for 2 months (extended access token):

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** get a permanent access token, but it is quite easy to renew after its expiration: [That](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) article is the way to go. The magic URL is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE&scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
```

- `client_id`
  The ID of your app. You **must** register a facebook app even though you are working "offline" with Java or such - but - there's no need to actually program the app. Just register the app so that you get a fixed app id (you need it here) and you'll be fine.
- `redirect_uri`
   That's the important step - facebook redirects to the uri given in redirect_uri and adds an "#access_token=..." to that uri. You can parse that uri to acquire the token:

Call the link above with a webbrowser, use `http://localhost` as redirect_uri and you'll be fine. The browser will attempt to call `http://localhost#access_token=....` and obviously fail, but you can parse the url to get the token. It is not a very straightforward process, but it works for me.